# Lumen - Create database connection at runtime

Tags: php, postgresql, sqlite, laravel, lumen

In a Lumen project, I need to create database connections on runtime, but I keep getting a "Database [...] not configured" error, each time I try to use a recently created connection.

This is my test code on routes.php:

```
<?php

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {

    $config = $app->make('config');
    $config->set('database.connections.retail_db', [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('RETAIL_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('RETAIL_DB_PORT', 5432),
        'database' => env('RETAIL_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('RETAIL_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('RETAIL_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => env('RETAIL_DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix'   => env('RETAIL_DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'schema'   => env('RETAIL_DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
    ]);
    return app('db')->connection('retail_db')->select("SELECT * FROM users");

});
```

This code is supposed to work on Laravel, but I can't find any information regarding Lumen.

I'm using the latest Lumen version.

Comment: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Comment: @ClaudioKing I've read the documentation, but if doesn't say anything about database connections at runtime.

Comment: how can we use $config = $app->make('config'); in controller's action?, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is one main problem with the method you are going for:

You did not initialize any configuration object. Lumen by default has no traditional config object set, until you create a `config` directory in your root folder.

As written in the [Lumen configuration docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/configuration):

> All of the configuration options for the Lumen framework are stored in the .env file.

The approach you are going for requires the traditional config object as used in Laravel.

*To get that object and your new `retail_db` database connection working:*

- Create a `config` folder in your project root
- Copy the file `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php` to this config folder
- Initialize the database configuration object in your `bootstrap/app.php` with `$app->configure('database');` (put it at line 28)

Your folder structure looks like this now:

```
├── app
├── bootstrap
├── config
   └── database.php
├── database
├── public
├── resources
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor
```

Of course you can remove those connections you don't need from the connections array in `app/config/database.php` by commenting or removing them completely.

**app/config/database.php**

```json
'connections' => [

        /*'testing' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
        ],*/

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', base_path('database/database.sqlite')),
            'prefix'   => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
            'strict'    => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', false),
        ],
]
```

Your **bootstrap/app.php** with the changes:

```php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

//$app->withFacades();
// $app->withEloquent();

$app->configure('database');
```

Now you can use the code you already have in your `routes.php`.

To delete your `retail_db` connection, just set it to `null`:

```php
$config->set('database.connections.retail_db', null);
```

Comment: Thank you @codedge this is what i need. But out of curiosity, how can i delete the newly created connection?

Comment: For deleting there is only the way, setting it to null - I updated, my answer.

Comment: how can we use $config = $app->make('config'); in controller's action?, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Put database.php file at config/database.php instead of app/config/database.php location and do not forget to comment/delete db credentials in .env file and restart lumen services by command line. It works. Thanks @codedge.

Comment: Hello, I'm using Lumen 8.2.3, when I create new project, I don't see config/database.php or config file, should I create new one? or there is command for create config file? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer @jhon's question
Lumen does not provides that config folder, you need to create at root the new directory called `config`.

Then inside it just copy what @codedge mentions about `database.php` file

> Copy the file vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php to this config folder

follow below commands in terminal to create the `config` directory and copy the `database.php` file

```
user$ cd projectPath/
user$ mkdir config
user$ cp vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php config/database.php
```

where *this config folder* is the `config` directory you just created.
so it would looks like the image below.
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVgAF.png)