# Lumen and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, lumen

I'm having issues with Lumen 5.3 when trying to return JSON responses after a query to my MySQL database.

My scheme and all of my tables are encoded in `utf8_general_ci`, and this is a sample of my code that causes me trouble :

```
public function getUserByMail(Request $request){
    $user = app('db')->table('user')->select('id','lastName', 'firstName','mail','status')->where('mail',$request->input('userMail'))->first();
    return response()->json(
        array('id' => $user->id,
            'lastName' => $user->lastName,
            'firstName' => $user->firstName,
            'mail' => $user->mail,
            'status' => $user->status));
}
```

**Sometimes** (but only sometimes), this piece of code throws an exception `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` when calling the `json()` method.

I don't know what to do to fix it, does anybody has an idea ?

Comment: try to var_dump the value that make this bug. Then you'll see what's wrong

Comment: Show us the connection code where you specify the _client's_ charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood what happened : as i was running Lumen on Wamp installation, i encountered this error because of a configuration loading issue.

The Lumen framework uses `DotEnv` to load the `.env` file which specifies database connection information. But in *SOME CASES* (i suspect PHP multi-threading support malfunctioning), my request used default database logins of Laravel (`forge@localhost`) to access database, which silently failed (the `PDOException` encountered wasn't caught by Lumen exception handler) and my `$user` variable didn't contain what i expected, which caused the UTF-8 bug.

This issue is referenced in Lumen GitHub ([here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/585)).

I fixed the issue using this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215265/lumen-create-database-connection-at-runtime/37243775#37243775) to force my configuration to be loaded.